# Loading and executing bundle from memory

Tags: macos, cocoa, bundle, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Loading bundle from memory is possible by NSCreateObjectFileImageFromMemory function. Does anyone have successful experience in this area? Does anyone have working sample for this function?
My code is as:

```
text srcPath = "/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit";
data_t data;
data.loadFromFile(srcPath);
void *addr;
kern_return_t err;
NSObjectFileImage img = nil;
NSObjectFileImageReturnCode dyld_err;

err = vm_allocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t *)&addr,
    data.length(), true);
if(err == 0)
{
    //err = vm_write(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)addr,
        //(vm_address_t)(char*)data, data.length());
    memcpy(addr, (char*)data, data.length());
    if(err == 0)
        dyld_err =
            NSCreateObjectFileImageFromMemory(addr, data.length(), &img);
        // error is NSObjectFileImageFailure
}
```

The **img** variable is null (error is NSObjectFileImageFailure). Why?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4-intel/man3/NSObjectFileImage.3.html), it looks like only `MH_BUNDLE` files can be loaded with `NSCreateObjectFileImageFromMemory()` and friends.

`MH_BUNDLE` files are explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html).

> The MH_BUNDLE file type is the type typically used by code that you
>   load at runtime (typically called bundles or plug-ins). By convention,
>   the file name extension for this format is .bundle.

Note that that manpage is for 10.4 and there does not appear to be a newer version available.

Comment: Thanks, I also have been created a simple bundle by XCode (has .bundle extension), but not successful.

Comment: Ok, I detected problem, 1. MH_BUNDLE files can be loaded and 2. both loader and bundle should have same architecture (both 32 or 64bit).